# What is this old PC truck game?

Tags: ibm-pc, identify-this-game

I've begun to recall a game I played as a child with my brother, and I can't remember what it was called for the life of me. The reason I'm asking for identification is because I remember how much he loved it. Christmas is coming up and I want to see if I can get it for him, along with a few other PC games we loved as kids, and rig up some hardware that can still run the game as a present for him. I would really appreciate if you guys can help me out in time for the holidays!

Here's everything I can remember about this game:

1. It was an old **PC game**, probably for **Windows XP**, since I think that was the computer we had at the time. For reference on the time frame, we also owned the old Lego Island games, the other half of my potential Christmas present.
2. It involved what I believe were either **Tonka trucks** or other non-branded **construction vehicles**. I seem to remember you could drive them around a **3D or 2D** environment, destroying and building things. You could control dump trucks, cranes and other heavy construction equipment.
3. There was definitely a **space or moon base level** where you could **drill into walls** and find secret tunnels using a drill truck of some kind, and I think the goal was to find a certain amount of a mineral which was hidden in the walls. I remember it being one of the more difficult stages, so it probably occurred later in the game.

**Does anyone remember the name of this game?** I've done a bit of research around the Internet but nothing I can find jogs my memory. If this question is too vague, I'll see what else I can remember about it and add more information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not RC related. Please try some gaming site.

Comment: Sorry, I figured since there were other retro game identifying questions this would be the best place to put it. Is there a more relevant stack exchange site I can migrate it to?

Comment: [Gaming.SC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) is a great and knowledgeable community for everything game related. So if it's about content I'd rather ask there first. People on RC do ofc, as well play games and do have natural knowledge, it's just less of a focus of RC.

Comment: Thank you, that's good advice. This question got answered here, but if I have another one in the future I'll make sure to ask Gaming first. I appreciate you taking time to provide clarification, you can probably tell I'm new here!

Comment: No harm done. There are many viewpoints toward a question.

Comment: I think the clause from the help pages may help out here: `Questions about modern, currently supported computers are off-topic. This includes questions about earlier versions of a current machine or OS.`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Since we have a tag "identify-this-game" I think the question is fine. Windows-XP is not a modern currently supported operating system, so an XP game is retro.

Comment: Jeremy, that would appear to be covered by the snippet `This includes questions about earlier versions of a current machine or OS`. XP is very much an earlier version of Win10.

Comment: I'm not sold on that second clause; have started a conversation on meta: https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/812/change-rule-preventing-questions-about-earlier-versions-of-a-current-machine

Comment: Given that Tonka Construction 2 is a Windows 95 game, I think this should be on-topic (but that's literally my only justification).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's [Tonka Construction 2 (1999)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEB7TDKdoz0) and similar games in the [series](http://tonka.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Video_Games), including one called Tonka Space Station, but that one looks like a racing game, not a mineral hunting game.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for!! The sounds and music just brought a wave of nostalgia back to me. Thank you so much! My brother will be very happy.