# What is this 2000s-era Windows XP or earlier educational computer game?

Tags: identify-this-game, identify-this-software

So I asked [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/what-is-this-old-pc-truck-game) a while back asking for help with identifying a retro computer game, and got the answer I was looking for. Thus, I've decided to ask for help identifying another retro game from my early childhood. This one must be really obscure, because I've scoured the Internet searching for it but can't find a single thing about it. I hope somebody remembers it too. (I also figured this question was appropriate for the Retrocomputing Exchange since Windows XP is a discontinued "retro" operating system.)

**Information**

The game was a **mid-2000s educational computer game**, probably for **Windows XP** (but it could also have been Windows 7?), which taught really basic arithmetic if I remember correctly - addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, on the level of 2 x 2 and 3 + 1. It had color graphics and I seem to recall it being colorful and well-illustrated.

The main game was laid out as a **board game**, kind of like a virtual version of the Candyland board, where each step on the board was a math-themed minigame. If you beat the minigame by solving math problems, you could advance to the next spot on the board. If you reached the end of the board, you won the game.

The minigames I specifically remember are:

- **Toucan Game:** A toucan that had different colors of berries, which you had to count.
- **Egyptian Tomb Game:** An Egyptian tomb where math problems were written on the sarcophagi, and you had to answer them quickly (I remember this minigame being particularly difficult for my younger self, and while I know the game is not Funky Mummy Addition, that is basically the idea of this minigame and how it worked.)

I'm almost positive that the game was *not* JumpStart, Reading Rabbit, etc. The graphics are not what I remember and they're laid out like adventure games, not board games.

I hope this is enough information for somebody to identify what it is! It's been bothering me for years.

Comment: Just so you know, we've [recently decided](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/278) against changing that XP [is off-topic](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/418/278), mostly because it's too similar to current versions of Windows. This apparently applies to software written for XP, too (I assume this is because the only on-topic-ness details we have are in the "off-topic" category). If this game ran on earlier versions of Windows too, though, it's probably on-topic – did it?

Comment: Also, do you remember the screen resolution / colour depth? Did it have the [distinctive dithering patterns](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1887/278)? Was it full-screen, or windowed?

Comment: Sorry for not seeing that discussion, I can close the question if it's off-topic. I don't keep up with stuff very well!

Comment: That's fine. And no need to close the question yourself; it's not definitely definitely under the "XP rule", so only vote to close if _you yourself_ think it's off topic.

Comment: I think I'll tentatively keep it open since there is a possibility it was for an earlier operating system - I'm not 100% positive it was for XP, it was just the computer I remember us having at the time. Thank you for being helpful and explaining the rules, you are a good mod :)

Comment: WHY IS THIS SITE SO CLOSE HAPPY THERES LIKE 5 POSTS A DAY

Comment: @dashnick as WizzWizz4 implied, you are free to vote to reopen this question.  I did.  With about 2 years being a computer generation, I think it is fair to consider something at least 6 generations back as "retro". // Regarding the question itself, I do not know the answer.